# Blending Multiple Git Repos

Tags: git, repository

Over the years I've pulled a single Git repo for a Content Management System (CMS) into an unlimited number of Git repos that become separate websites for each of our Clients. The root for each site looks similar to below.

```
<root>
 _css <CMS directory>
   ├─── styles.css <CMS file>
 _ext <Custom code specific to website>
   ├─── _css
          ├─── styles.css <Custom file>
   ├─── _ext
   ├─── _forms
   ├─── _img
   ├─── _inc
   ├─── _js
   ├─── _lib
   ├─── _proc
   ├─── _tmplt
 _forms <CMS directory>
 _img <CMS directory>
 _inc <CMS directory>
 _js <CMS directory>
 _lib <CMS directory>
 _proc <CMS directory>
 _tmplt <CMS directory>
 index.html <CMS file>
 login.html < " >
 secure.html < " >
 contact.html <Custom file specific to website>
 legal.html < " >
 products.html < " >
 sitemap.xml < " >
```

The directory and files marked with 'CMS', are contained in one git repo and form the foundation of any website we host.

The gitignore for the 'CMS' repo is below:

```
# Ignore files #
/*
/*/

# Un-ignore CMS root files and directories
!/_css/
!/_forms/
!/_img/
!/_inc/
!/_js/
!/_lib/
!/_proc/
!/_tmplt/
!index.html
!login.html
!secure.html

# Ignore Custom files and directories #
/_ext/
sitemap.xml
```

Each Client's website is a separate directory and a separate repo. Each Client website .gitignore(s)  the '_ext' directory, and three root files (index.hmtl, login.html and secure.html), as they are pulled from the 'CMS' repo.

Any files in the '_ext' directory, are specific to a Client's website, and supplant or supersede files with the same name, in the root directories with the same name as the 'CMS'. Any files in the root directory, apart from the three 'CMS' files, can be created on the fly by the Content Management System, so that's why the CMS ignores them.

In short, when within a Client repo, Client files are pushed and pulled, but 'CMS' files are only ever pulled (from the 'CMS' repo).

I'm starting to have issues pulling the 'CMS' repo, it not updated the Client website with the latest files, and I'm wondering if this is the best configuration for our purpose.

I've tried submodules, but that doesn't work when the pulled repo places files anywhere but a subdirectory.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What issue did you have pulling CMS?

Comment: If I understand correctly, this process should work, though having separate repos for each client sounds like an overkill. A single repo where you have a single branch for each client should suffice. Anyway..... I second @BillMorgan's comment. What problem do you see when you try to pull?

Comment: The problem with pulling the 'CMS' is that none of the files from that repo are updated. I've tried using <git fetch --all> AND THEN <git reset --hard origin/master> as advised in other posts, but it's not working...